# Django how to redirect back to pagination page after update data?

Tags: python, django

I am using paginator in my list view. Every page listed 10 item. If I edit an item from page 5 then I want to redirect back to page 5. Right if I edit an team from page 5, it's redirecting me every time in page 1. here is my code:

```
class ApproveCommentPage(PermissionRequiredMixin,UpdateView):

      raise_exception = True

      permission_required = ("blog.add_commentblog","blog.change_commentblog","blog.delete_commentblog","blog.view_commentblog")

      model = BlogComment

      template_name = "approve_comment.html"

      form_class =AdminComment
             

      def get_success_url(self):

                    return reverse_lazy('blog-admin') #when using this success_url my comment updated and redirected to first page.
```

**#updated question. here is my list view**

```
class CommentList(PermissionRequiredMixin,ListView):
      raise_exception = True
      permission_required = ("blog.add_commentblog","blog.change_commentblog","blog.delete_commentblog","blog.view_commentblog")
      model =BlogComment
      template_name ="admin.html"
      paginate_by = 10
      ordering =["-blog_id"]
```

my **urls.py**

```
 path('blog-admin/',CommentList.as_view(),name='blog-admin'), #this is the list page where I listed my comment.
 path('blog-admin/comment-approve/<int:pk>/',ApproveCommentPage.as_view(),name='comment-approve') #this is the edit page where I am editing the comment
```

**admin.html** I am listing my all comment in admin.html. Each page have 10 comment in admin.html

my admin.html look like this
[image]

here is code of my **admin.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'comment-approve' pk=blogcomment.pk %}?page={{ page_obj.number }}">{% csrf_token %}approve {{ blogcomment.name }}
<input type="submit" value="{{ blogcomment.name }}"></form>

<!-- Pagination-->
<ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-4">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=1">First Page</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">← Back</a></li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next Page →</a></li>
    
    {% endif %}

    {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
    {% if page_obj.number == i %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#!">{{ i }}</a></li>
      
    {% elif i > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and i < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
    {%endif%}
    {% endfor %}

    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last Page</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- Pagination-->
```

#my **approval_commnet.html** where I am editing comment:

```
<form  method="POST" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            
            
            <button class="btn btn-info">Publish</button>
        </form>
```

**#updated question**
when added this `<form action="{% url 'blog-admin' %}?page={{  page_obj.number }}" method="post">` in my approval_commnet html and below code in my update view:

```
def get_success_url(self):
        res = reverse('blog-admin')
        if 'page' in self.request.GET:
            res += f"?page={self.request.GET['page']}"
        return res
```

I am getting this **HTTP ERROR 405** when click on update button. See the picture
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<form>` you can attach the current page, so something like:

```
<form action="{% url 'name-of-some-url' %}?page={{ page_obj.number }}" method="post">
    …
</form>
```

then we can redirect to the correct page:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class ApproveCommentPage(PermissionRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    # …

    def get_success_url(self):
        res = reverse('blog-admin')
        if 'page' in self.request.GET:
            res += f"?page={self.request.GET['page']}"
        return res
```

Comment: Willem Van Onsem Thanks for your answer. I added `<form method="POST" action="{% url 'blog-admin' %}?page={{ page_obj.page }}"> `  in my from but getting HTTP ERROR 405.

Comment: @boyenec: can you edit the question with what you see in the console log?

Comment: getting this this url in HTTP ERROR 405 page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog-admin/?page=` and here is console log `[10/Jun/2021 00:53:47] "POST /blog-admin/?page= HTTP/1.1" 405 0`

Comment: @boyenec: but the `{{ page_obj.page }}` should present the page number. So you should take a look to your listview to find out how you can retrieve the *current* page.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem I updated my question. see my list view. I am not understanding why it's not working. It's seems to me no problems in your code.

Comment: @boyenec: can you also share relevant parts about the `admin.html` template (sorry, but likely there is a small error somewhere).

Comment: Yes. Definately

Comment: @boyenec: I already found one problem: it is `?page={{ page_obj.number }}`, so not `.page`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233575/discussion-between-boyenec-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: Willem Van Onsem Will I sent you google drive link of my admin.html?? or Update my question?

Comment: @boyenec: if it is not too long, you can do that in the question body. You can also filter out a lot of the template that is not relevant

Comment: Willem Van Onsem  here is google drive link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A_sfe74_i0sTl3s7Zsmaz5g5XN7UWzo2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @boyenec: you use a simple `<form>` instead of the `<form>` that makes a POST request to the `ApproveCommentPage`?

Comment: Willem Van Onsem I updated my question

Comment: Willem Van Onsem  you said to use this `<form action="{% url 'blog-admin' %}?page={{ page_obj.number }}"method="POST" >`  in my update forms. This was the mail culprit for error. I just used `<form method="POST">` in my update forms and it worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233602/discussion-between-boyenec-and-willem-van-onsem).